# PDF is cutting down from right when exporting using node js html-pdf

Tags: node.js, pdf, html-pdf

I am having a task in my project to convert a html file into pdf. It has been done successfully using html-pdf. But the problem is when I am running this in my localhost the pdf coming fine but if I am try this same at our development server then the pdf has been cutting down from right wise.

My pdf generation script is

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('ticket.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('pdf/newpdftemplate.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
```

Please suggest if any settings I need to change or add any new script to do this.

Also sharing the html script here

```
<div class="pageContatiner noSelect ui-droppable slctCon" style="width: 6px; height: 500px;"><span class="bd1"></span><span class="bd2"></span><span class="bd3"></span><span class="bd4"></span><div class="ft-container"><div onmousedown="objSelection(this)" ontouchstart="objSelection(this)" id="pmObj-1" class="shape obj ft-widget" style="left: 330px; top: 118px; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute;-webkit-transform:none;-moz-transform:none;-o-transform:none;transform:none;-ms-transform:none;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="102" width="102"><rect class="svgObj" x="1" y="1" height="100" width="100" stroke="rgba(51,122,183,0.99)" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(51,122,183,1)"></rect></svg></div><div class="ft-controls" style="top: 118.333px; left: 330px; width: 100px; height: 100px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; visibility: hidden;"><div class="ft-rotator" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; top: -20px; left: 66px;"><i class="fa fa-undo" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="ft-delete"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="ft-check"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-top ft-scaler-left ft-scaler-tl"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-top ft-scaler-right ft-scaler-tr"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-bottom ft-scaler-right ft-scaler-br"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-bottom ft-scaler-left ft-scaler-bl"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-top ft-scaler-center ft-scaler-tc"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-bottom ft-scaler-center ft-scaler-bc"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-mid ft-scaler-left ft-scaler-ml"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-mid ft-scaler-right ft-scaler-mr"></div><div class="ft-scaler ft-scaler-mid ft-scaler-center ft-scaler-mc"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: try using other format in your options like A4 or A5,`var options = { format: 'A4' };` otherwise you can also specify the width and the height in options e.g.
`var options = {  "width": "15cm"};`

Comment: Yes tried that. But not working

Comment: Ok, can you share your html file? it may be because of the width of elements you used in the html.

Comment: Yes I have edited my question with the html script. Its running fine in my local server . so not sure if anything here is server dependent

Comment: how did you fix this? I am also facing this issue.